# How to coverage HttpErrorResponse in Angular

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am trying to coverage below HttpErrorResponse code coverage by Jasmin framework but its not getting to cover.

### component

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (navigator.onLine) {
      const headers = new HttpHeaders().set(InterceptorSkipHeader, '')
      this.loginService.login(form.value, headers).subscribe(data => {
        const serverData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        if (serverData.status == 'success') {
          localStorage.setItem(GlobalVariables.AUTHERIZATION_TOEKN, serverData.access_token);
          localStorage.setItem(GlobalVariables.USER_ID, serverData.userId);
          this.router.navigate([""]);
        } else {
          this.toast.error(serverData.message, "Fail!");
        }
      }, (errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (errorResponse.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
          this.toast.error(errorResponse.error.message, "Client Error");
        } else {
          this.toast.error(errorResponse.error.message, "Server Error");
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.toast.error(GlobalVariables.CHECK_INTERNET_CONNECTION, "Fail!");
    }
  }
```

### test class

```
 it('Check login component', () => {
    const errorResponse = new HttpErrorResponse({
      error: '404 error',
      status: 404,
      statusText: 'Not Found'
    });
    let testForm = <NgForm>{
      value: {
        userName: "sample",
        password: "sample"
      }
    };
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    let response;
    spyOn(service,'login').and.returnValue(of(errorResponse));
    service.login(testForm.value,headers).subscribe(
      data => fail('Should have failed with 404 error'),
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        expect(error.status).toEqual(404);
        expect(error.error).toContain('404 error');
      }
    );
    component.onSubmit(testForm);
  });
```

### not covered code

```
(errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (errorResponse.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
          this.toast.error(errorResponse.error.message, "Client Error");
        } else {
          this.toast.error(errorResponse.error.message, "Server Error");
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.toast.error(GlobalVariables.CHECK_INTERNET_CONNECTION, "Fail!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need individual tests for the successful and the error cases (two tests for each case to have the `if` and the `else` path covered). They basically differ in the way you mock the `loginService.login` method and of course in the expected result.

For the **successful** case, you mock `loginService.login` as follows (with different `successResponse` for the `if` and the `else` path):

```
spyOn(service,'login').and.returnValue(of(successResponse));
```

For the **error** case, `loginService.login` needs to be mocked as shown below:

`if` path...

```
const errorEvent = <ErrorEvent> { message: 'something bad happened' };
const errorResponse = new HttpErrorResponse({
    error: errorEvent
});    
spyOn(service,'login').and.returnValue(throwError(errorResponse));
```

`else` path...

```
const errorResponse = new HttpErrorResponse({
    error: '404 error',
    status: 404,
    statusText: 'Not Found'
});    
spyOn(service,'login').and.returnValue(throwError(errorResponse));
```

Comment: let me try and tell result

Comment: only else block covered but not cover if block inside HttpErrorResponse

Comment: @AbhiRam: That's because `errorResponse.error` is not an `instanceof ErrorEvent` but a `string`. To have full coverage, you need again another test for the `if`case.

Comment: spyOn(service,'login').and.returnValue(throwError(new ErrorEvent('network Error')));

Comment: i used above code but not covered yet can you please guide with code

Comment: @AbhiRam: I updated my answer with untested proposals for the `if/else` paths of the error case.

Answer (score 0):

It is because in your test you're calling the service whereas the code not covered is in the component code.

You need to call the `component.onSubmit` instead of `service.login.subscribe.`